# No luck with vertical align middle

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the most cross browser and straight forward way of vertically aligning and horizontally aligning my form on the page. I have read that this should do this but when I put it in my CSS it still sits at the top.

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

I believe I have got it horizontally aligned correctly but cannot for the life of my get it aligned vertically.

One way was possible to use this but apparently this is not very cross browser

```
display: table-cell
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/q28WR/21/
- http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/q28WR/21/embedded/result/

This is how far I've got so far.an anyone please help me understand why not?

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers support table-cell. [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-table)

Various methods of vertically centring are discussed [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/). If the form can be given a fixed height then **absolute positioning and negative margins** could work.

Comment: Negative margins do not work well if horizontal scrolling is necessary.

Comment: Table-cell still isn't supporting to the extent I am after, and i'm not having any luck integrating the other methods (I was trying to use method three in your link)

Comment: Good point PointedEars. Vertically centring seems like hard work. Just add some content above the form and use a top-margin to push it a bit further down ;). The concept of height is an anomaly for a web page. @JamesWilson That linked-page has further links a bit further down.